# Permutation problem.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Six different pencils and three bags are taken. Each pencil has to be put in one of the bags. No bag should remain empty and all bags should not have same number of pencils. In how many ways can this be done?

---

The above problem looks like computing number of surjective functions first and then subtracting the cases when all bags have same number of pencils.

Number of surjective functions possible =$540$.

Number of ways all bags will have same number of pencils = $(6!)/(2! * 2! * 2!) = 90$.

So I think answer should be $540 - 90 = 450$. But answer is given as $444$.

Am I over counting any combinations?

Comment: Did you exclude the $6$ possibilities of $(0, 0, 6)$?

Comment: Are the bags to be treated identical or non identical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct. As well as checking the argument you gave (and that the number of surjective functions is $3^6-3\times 2^6+3\times 1^6=540$), I quickly counted the valid arrangements in python:

```
from itertools import product
print(sum(1 for x in product(range(3),repeat=6) if all(y in x for y in range(3)) and any(x.count(y)!=2 for y in range(3))))
```

This also gives $450$.